# How to output the label of points in scatterplot to bash console

Tags: r, bash, plot

I have a simple R-Script:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

inp <- read.csv(args[1],sep="\t",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

firstCol <- inp$V2
secondCol <- inp$V3

pdf(args[2])
plot(firstCol,secondCol,xlab="#",ylab="maxLength")
dev.off()
```

I run it from a bash script to generate a basic plot.

Now I want to use `X11()` to plot directly into a window and not into a PDF.

What I want now is to appear the label (in `inp$V1`) of every dot on the console when hovering over a point or klicking onto it.

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `identify` function lets you click on points and it returns the index value for the points clicked on that could be used to subset a vector of labels.

For identification when hovering (instead of clicking) you can look at the `HTKidentify` function in the TeachingDemos package.

**Edit**

Here is an example using `identify` that may be more what you want (I tested it on windows, not unix/X11):

```
x <- runif(26)
y <- rnorm(26)
plot(x,y)
while(length(tmp <- identify(x,y, plot=FALSE, n=1))) {
  cat(letters[tmp],'\n')
}
```

The `plot=FALSE` tells identify to not put the label on the plot and the `n=1` tells it to return after you click on 1 point (the `while` goes back to identifying more points, but prints out the label immediately).

Obviously you would create other labels to use than just the letters.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I tried already identify. Was not satisfied. Will try HTKidentify.

Comment: @Michael, how was `identify` less than satisfactory?  what was your code? we may be able to show you how to better use that function.

Comment: It prints onto the plot itself. But as stated in my question I would like to output the label on the bash console. This, because at some places I have a high density of dots and then I can not read the label well. OR if I could define where the label gets printed to (like in one corner or so).

Comment: @Michael, I added an example of some code wrapped around `identify` that does more what you describe.